# MATLAB Double Integral using Trapezoidal Rule

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have to use trapezoidal composite rule to integrate:

```
%f.m
function [ab]=f(x,y)
ab = sqrt((exp(sin(x.*pi - y.*pi)))+(exp(cos(x.*y.*pi))))
```

and my trapezoidal function:

```
%trap.m
function [T] = trap(a,b,N)
h=(b-a)./N;
x=a+[0:N]*h;
y=f(x);
T=(y(1)+y(N+1)+2*sum(y(2:N)))*h/2
```

I am confused as to how I would do this double integration, but I was thinking Iit would have got something like:

```
%main.m
clear;
Tr = zeros(6);
a=0;
b=3 ; 
N = 2.^([1:10]);

for i=1:2:10,
    [Tr(i)]=trap(a, b, N(i), %first integration); %second integration...
end
```

My trap function would take the first integration?

Comment: Can you state your question clearly? Do you want to change your trap function to accomodate double integration or do you want to do it outside as you are attempting to do in main script ? Either way, y=f(X) will not work in your trap function because f takes in two arguments.

Comment: also just curious why are you not using inbuilt trapz function of matlab ?

Comment: @PagMax trap.m and f.m I used for single integration and now I want to use it for double integration but am not sure how. I was thinking of doing so by changing my trap function so it would take another parameter but I also don't know how I can do so. Unless there is another way to do double integration. 

A was not using trapz because I was wondering how to do it this way, but it seems a little hard.

Answer (score 0):

In the one-dimensional trapezoidal rule the function values are multiplied by h/2, h, h, ..., h, h/2 where h is the step size. These are the *weights* of this integration rule. When an integration rule is applied in two dimensions, the weights get *multiplied*. In general you'll have different step sizes in two dimensions, say, h1 and h2, and the weights will be h1*h2 multiplied by the following numbers:

```
1/4 1/2 1/2 1/2 1/4
1/2  1   1   1  1/2
1/2  1   1   1  1/2
1/4 1/2 1/2 1/2 1/4
```

A quick way to implement this is to add all the values, subtract 1/2 of values on each side (this subtracts off the corners twice), then add 1/4 of corner values. There is no need for `for` loops: you can use `meshgrid` for setting up the grid for evaluations, and `sum` for double summation. Example:

```
f = @(x,y) sqrt((exp(sin(x.*pi - y.*pi)))+(exp(cos(x.*y.*pi))));
a1 = 0; b1 = 3; N1 = 20;
h1 = (b1-a1)/N1;
a2 = -1; b2 = 4; N2 = 30;
h2 = (b2-a2)/N2;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(a1:h1:b1, a2:h2:b2);
Z = f(X,Y); 
T = h1*h2*(sum(Z(:)) - 0.5*(sum(Z(1,:)+Z(end,:)) + sum(Z(:,1)+Z(:,end))) + 0.25*(Z(1,1)+Z(1,end)+Z(end,1)+Z(end,end)))
```

The last line precisely corresponds to what I said above: adding all values, subtracting 1/2 of edges, adding 1/4 of corners.

Comment: Why is N1=20 and N2=30? Is this just an example? Also thank you, it's a little complicated.

Comment: Yes, just an example. I wanted to give a complete working example, not taking any parameters from outside. Normally you would have a function with parameters there.